# Ecma script, поведение объектов

Tags: объекты, ecmascript-6, export

Всем привет

```
let func1 = function() {};
let func2 = function() {};

export default {
  func1,
  func2
}
```

В этом случае (т.к. ecma считает это сокращенной записью) на экспорт уходит объект вида:

```
{
  func1: func1,
  func2: func2
}
```

Но мне необходим объект, как он есть, т.е.:

```
{
  func1,
  func2
}
```

Решил это путём:

```
export default Object.assign(
  {},
  func1,
  func2
);
```

Но как мне помнится, IE не дружит с Object и придётся подключать polyfill либу.

Вопрос - как мне это обойти?

Если это не обойти красивыми путями, то другой вопрос - делается это все на VueJs, сокращенный код выше берет getters (func1 и func2) из разных файлов, собирается и отдается на экспорт в store. Уверен, что есть более красивое решение, например, забрать весь экспорт с папки или что-то вроде того.

Спасибо.

Comment: А Object.assign(func1, func2); у вас копирует свойства func2 в func1 и возвращает func1?

Comment: Да, в данном случае это работает так. Object.assign({}, func1, func2); отдает тот же результат в моем случае, просто новый экземпляр объекта. Здесь вопрос именно в "фитчах ecma", она читает запись {p1, p2} как {p1: p1, p2: p2} и поэтому, если использовать такую запись - появляется дополнительная вложенность.

Comment: Какая-то ерунда в коде...

Comment: Почему ерунда? Не претендую на магистра в экме и готов услышать конструктив.